# OpenGL door animation

Tags: opengl, animation

I'm trying to animate a door so that if I press a button the door will open. At the moment it compiles, and when I go to press the button it moves the camera and then I can't control the camera anymore. What is wrong with the code?

```
glPushMatrix;
glTranslatef (door_Xpos,0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef (door_Angle, 1,0,0);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

//Door left
glColor3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
glVertex3f(-10.0, 0.0, -25.0);
glColor3f(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f);
glVertex3f(-10.0, 15.0, -25.0);
glColor3f(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f);
glVertex3f(0.0, 15.0, -25.0);
glColor3f(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -25.0);

//door right
glColor3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
glVertex3f(10.0, 0.0, -25.0);
glColor3f(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f);
glVertex3f(10.0, 15.0, -25.0);
glColor3f(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f);
glVertex3f(0.0, 15.0, -25.0);
glColor3f(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -25.0);

glPopMatrix;

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            glTranslatef(5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            break;

        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            glTranslatef(-5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            break;

        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 5.0);
            break;

        case 's':
        case 'S':
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
            break;

        case 't':
        case 'T':
            if (is_depth)
            {
                is_depth = 0;
                glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            }
            else
            {
                is_depth = 1;
                glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            }

        #Fall-through...
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            door_Xpos += 90.0;
            break;
    }
    display();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL is not a scene graph, *glTranslate*, *glRotate* and similar don't move objects around, they change the transformation applied to triangles drawn to the screen. Thus it makes no sense to call matrix manipulations functions in an event handler. Actually most OpenGL functions, that includes matrix manipulation, are to be called from the *display* function. The only exception to this rule are data uploads like textures or buffer object data.

Try animating your door from within the display function based on **variables** set by the event handlers.